# What does this unboundLocal error refers in this python code?

Tags: python

I received this error:
"UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment"

```
def solution(number):
   if number <=10:
        for i in range(10):
             if int(i/3) | int(i/5):
                s+=i 
   return s
```

Comment: What is `s`? You don't seem to define it. The error seems pretty self-descriptive, actually....

Comment: You're trying to add things to a variable that has no value yet.